# How to pass a parameter to declare generic type list?

Tags: c#, list, generics, types

```
private void listHelper (int listSize, ref Object taker, Object giver, Type type)
    {
        if (listSize == 0)
        {
            taker = null;
        }
        else
        {
            taker = new List<type>(listSize);
            giverType tempGiver;
            for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
            {
                type= new type();
                tempGiver.value = giver[i];
                taker.Add(tempGiver);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my code. I have tried to pass a type parameter to the private method to declare generic type list... But I have no idea what to do.

parameter taker is a list. In this case, taker is storing a generic type of object.
parameter type is a type of the generic.

I have searched about this on the internet for a while. I am still not sure how to do this.

Comment: I can't follow what you're trying to do here.  Could you write an explanation of what you're trying to actually achieve?  Are you trying to copy a list?

Answer (score 10):

Try making a generic method instead:

```
private void listHelper<T> (int listSize, out List<T> taker, IList<T> giver)
{
    if (listSize == 0)
    {
        taker = null;
    }
    else
    {
        taker = new List<T>(listSize);
        for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
        {
            taker.Add(giver[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Also I suggest using `out` rather than `ref` (as I have done) since you always assign a value to `taker` before returning. This allows the calling code to not have to assign a dummy value before calling your method.

Or better yet, you should just *return the List*!

```
private List<T> listHelper<T> (int listSize, IList<T> giver)
{
    List<T> taker;
    ...
    return taker;
}
```

---

Note, if all your method is doing is copying all elements from `giver` to `taker` (that is, specifying `listSize` is really just a holdover habit from coding C and always equals the number of elements in `giver`), you can either substitute `giver.Count` or just do:

```
private List<T> listHelper<T> (IList<T> giver)
{
    return giver.Any() ? giver.ToList() : null;
}
```

Of course, if `listSize` is really "number of elements to return, starting at the front of `giver`", you can do:

```
private List<T> listHelper<T> (IList<T> giver, int numElements)
{
    return giver.Any() ? giver.Take(numElements).ToList() : null;
}
```

---

In fact, reading into your question further, it looks like you want to instantiate a new object of some type and set *it's `value` property to the item in `giver`*. So how about this (of course I'm assuming a lot about your `taker` object and that you have an interface `ITaker<U>` which specifies a field/property `public U value`):

```
private List<T<U>> listHelper<T, U> (IList<U> giver) where T : ITaker<U>, new()
{
    return giver.Any() ? giver.Select(g => new T<U>() {value = g}).ToList() : null;
}
```

Comment: Better to drop listSize in favor of giver.Count

Comment: @HenkHolterman Agreed, but I wonder if there's something else going on with `listSize` that we don't know about

Answer (score 2):

I guess its something like:

```
private void ListHelper<T>(int listSize, ref object taker, object giver)
{
    ...
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a Generic method.  Generics act as templates in C#.  The method is bound when it's declared.

```
public void ListHelper<T>//...

    List<T>  my list//...
```